# I want to create unorder list. What is the best solutions ?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uilabel

I want to create unorder list. UIwebView is good but it's very heavy (there is some lags). NSLabel is good but it is very hard to calculate the dot's offset if we have multistring text.
What is the best solutions ?

[image: unorder list]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to create Labels for this.

Create an Addition for `UILabel` to add the dot to a label and loop threw the dataSource. That's the way i would do this.